# Why is webpack bundling files of the same type differently?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, markdown, create-react-app

In my assets folder I have 6 markdown files. For some reason 5 of them are correctly getting encoded to base64, while one is getting packed like this:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "static/media/Online_Help_Glossary.f409e2b9.md";
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to possibly fix it? There is nothing unique about the contents of that file so I don't understand why it is behaving differently.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your webpack config.

Comment: What are the file sizes?

Comment: @sdgluck The way our stuff is setup we don't have access to the config.

Comment: @DaveNewton File sizes range from 1-15kb

Comment: @Alison That is problematic as if this is an issue with the webpack configuration then you will not be able to debug or test solutions. I suggest you make an attempt through the necessary channels to gain access to it or a copy of it.

Comment: It's likely there's a config to include "small" files directly and require larger ones, but you don't mention what's different about the one being packaged differently, so can't help much.

Comment: @DaveNewton the only thing different about the one being packaged differently is that it is larger. It has a large-ish html table whereas the rest have either a small table or just a few lines of text

Comment: Yep, so what I'm saying is that the default config for whatever webmack-markdown thing you're using has a setting for the max filesize to include directly, e.g., images. So check the plugin to see, if there's nothing there, check webpack docs.